# Select all rows which column has not already returned existing result

Tags: mysql

I am trying to pull records up from a mysql database but I want the result in one column to be completely unique

below is an example table

```
fname  | lname  | Street
-----------------------
john   | brown  | camelot st
george | kent   | camelot st
fred   | kent   | johnston rd
jane   |williams| camelot st
jack   | johnson| archer dr
james  | smith  | bruce st
adam   | smith  | james dr
```

below is the results I would want

```
Street
-----------
camelot st
johnston rd
archer dr
bruce st
james dr
```

in other words the first time any street name is returned it should display in the results after the first time it is no longer unique in the result and it should be omitted.

How would I manage this in mysql

Comment: You haven't really specified what strategy you want to take to determine which specific row of data will be shown when there are duplicates on that column.

Comment: it doesnt matter - in fact I am only pulling it to get 1 result of every existing street name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tableName 
WHERE street IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT street FROM tableName
) LIMIT 1;
```

This query should answer your question. However, it is important to note that you should order by an id field, because otherwise there is no guarantee that the rows in your database will always be queried in the same order.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT street
FROM address  
completes exactly what I need done